# Finding characters in a string based on white spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to get a function working that will return a new list of single characters that immediately follow two other given characters. Like so:

```
def filter_possible_chars(corpus, last):
    """
    >>> filter_possible_chars('lazy languid line', 'la')
    ['z', 'n']
    >>> filter_possible_chars('pitter patter', 'tt')
    ['e', 'e']
    """
    char_list = []
    corpus_split = corpus.split()
    for word in corpus_split:
        if last in word:
            word_split = word.split(last)
            follows_last = word_split[1]
            char_list.append(follows_last[0])
    return char_list
```

This function works perfectly for the examples given in the docstring, however I need to include examples that include white space, e.g.:

```
>>> filter_possible_chars('when the goat jumped to the rock', ' t')
```

And it would return:

```
['h', 'o', 'h']
```

But since my function is obviously deleting the white space I think I need to try an entirely different method here. I thought about not splitting the string into individual words and trying to index into it with the given letters, but I cannot think of a way to make that work for more than one instance in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> pat="tt"
>>> corpus="pitter patter"
>>> print(re.findall("%s(.)"%pat,corpus))
['e', 'e']
>>> corpus,pat = 'when the goat jumped to the rock', ' t'
>>> re.findall("%s(.)"%pat,corpus)
['h', 'o', 'h']
>>> corpus,pat = 'lazy languid line', 'la'
>>> re.findall("%s(.)"%pat,corpus)
['z', 'n']
```

#### Explanation

- `%` is the [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) operator, so for example `"%s(.)" % "la"` evaluates to `"la(.)"`.
- In [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), `.` is the pattern for "any character", and `()` define *groups* whose values can be retrieved later, e.g. using [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

  > If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups

So, for example, the pattern `la(.)` means "search for `la` followed by any character, and capture that character".

Comment: OK nice that's fantastic. Could you explain what the `re.findall("%s(.)"%pat,corpus)` is doing exactly? I am familiar with the `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)` but am not sure exactly what your symbols are doing or what they mean in your pattern parameter.

Comment: @RobertHemingway `re.findall()` searches for all non-overlapping matches of a regex pattern in a string. `'%s(.)' % pat` is saying "give me the first character after that regex pattern". The `(.)` denotes any single character except newline.

Comment: I like the fact that you explained basics of regular expression you used (so upvote for your answer). But in general I think that it's better not to use regular expressions as long as you don't really need it.

Comment: this is a very basic regex, there is no good reason to avoid it here.... but i do hear what your saying... but by that logic you never use regular expressions, because theres always more than one way to skin a cat...

Answer (score 3):

Your idea how to solve this issue is perfectly fine. Instead of splitting sentence into words you should try to find all instances of `last` in full `corpus`. But hey, actually `split` function can do this for you.

```py
corpus = 'when the goat jumped to the rock'
spl = corpus.split(' t')
print spl
>> ['when', 'he goat jumped', 'o', 'he rock']
res = [x[0] for x in spl[1:] if len(x) > 0]
print res
>> ['h', 'o', 'h']
```

So you can split `corpus` by `last` then get all strings from result of split without first one (as it does not start with `last`) and then get first letter from each such string.